# Change password request is logging out sensitive information

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently using the Microsoft Graph Java SDK (`microsoft-graph` v2.3.1) to change a user's password like so:

```cs
graphServiceClient
  .me()
  .changePassword(currentPassword, newPassword)
  .buildRequest()
  .post();
```

However, when the Graph API throws an exception, the change password request is written to the log  with the passwords displaying in plain text! Is there a way of hiding this sensitive information? For now, I have added a custom logger the Graph Server Client which in effect suppresses logging but I was wondering if there was something more fine grained in the SDK?

Comment: This certainly seems like a problem! That said, I would suggest posting to the SDK's [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java/issues) as well.  StackOverflow is an amazing resource but this is more of a bug report than a programming question.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll create an issue!

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/685